# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist()

Tags: php, apache, wamp, imap, drush

i imported a webproject under drupal 7 cms and i'm facing this error on sending email using drush in terminal typing this command (drush queue-mail-send-all) :

```
$ drush queue-mail-send-all
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist() in C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\all\modules\
custom\example\example.module on line 96
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php:0
PHP   2. drush_main() C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php:16
PHP   3. _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch() C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php:61
PHP   4. drush_dispatch() C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php:92
PHP   5. call_user_func_array() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:182
PHP   6. drush_command() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:182
PHP   7. _drush_invoke_hooks() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:214
PHP   8. call_user_func_array() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:362
PHP   9. drush_queue_mail_send_all() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:362
PHP  10. queue_mail_send() C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\all\modules\contrib\queue_mail\queue_mail.drush.inc:58
PHP  11. HTMLMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem->format() C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\all\modules\contrib\queue_mail\queue_mail.module:102
PHP  12. HTMLMailSystem->format() C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\default\files\mailsystem\HTMLMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem.mail.inc:20
PHP  13. theme() C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\all\modules\contrib\htmlmail\htmlmail.mail.inc:51
PHP  14. example_preprocess_htmlmail() C:\wamp\www\example.com\includes\theme.inc:1122

Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist() in C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\all\modules\custom\example\example.module on line 96

Call Stack:
    0.0010     152632   1. {main}() C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php:0
    0.1120    1764552   2. drush_main() C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php:16
    1.7801    4843496   3. _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch() C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php:61
   58.5523   40781840   4. drush_dispatch() C:\ProgramData\Drush\drush.php:92
   61.0695   40787544   5. call_user_func_array() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:182
   61.0695   40787640   6. drush_command() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:182
   61.0705   40787800   7. _drush_invoke_hooks() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:214
   61.0895   40819048   8. call_user_func_array() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:362
   61.0895   40819144   9. drush_queue_mail_send_all() C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\command.inc:362
   61.2285   40873112  10. queue_mail_send() C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\all\modules\contrib\queue_mail\queue_mail.drush.inc:58
   61.2315   40874976  11. HTMLMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem->format() C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\all\modules\contrib\queue_mail\queue_mail.module:102
   61.2315   40875000  12. HTMLMailSystem->format() C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\default\files\mailsystem\HTMLMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem.mail.inc:20
   61.2315   40876840  13. theme() C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\all\modules\contrib\htmlmail\htmlmail.mail.inc:51
   90.3282   58206648  14. example_preprocess_htmlmail() C:\wamp\www\trustedco

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
m[error]?[0m
Error: Call to undefined function imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist() in
C:\wamp\www\example.com\sites\all\modules\custom\example\example.module
```

-i can send emails with normal php function.
-i enabled imap in php.ini.
-i eneabled impap in wamp setting as php extention.
-my php version is : 5.4.16
-my apache version is : 2.4.4
- I'm using wamp server 64 X
- my OS windows 7 : 64 bit

[image]

i was trying to google this error for 3 days but i didnt find something helpfull

Comment: Did you restart PHP after enabling the extension? (restart Apache)

Comment: @N A T H sur i restard the my server with all services even my computer i'm trying from 3 days to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

I am running Windows 7 64bit environment with WAMP server, it has two `php.ini` files:

1. `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin`
   Enable `php_imap.dll` extension by removing `;` at beginning of string
2. `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16`
   Enable `php_imap.dll` extension by removing `;` at beginning of string

Comment: The version on `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini` is actually a SYMLINK to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\phpForApache.ini`  is used by Apache. The version in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.ini` is used by PHP CLI (Command Line Interface)